# Android emulator cam

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi can anyone please help me out to connect my web cam to android emulator?

Comment: Is it correct to assume that you want to try out and debug an app which should manage/display a camera feed? What kind of connection does your web cam permit to physical devices? WLAN and/or Bluetooth? Do you have a particular model in mind, or is this a generic question?

Comment: Or do you want to simulate a built-in camera using a web cam?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for using a web cam to simulate a built-in camera, [the emulator does not /yet) support video/image capture](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#limitations).

Answer (score 0):

It should be working in the latest Android SDK, and Android 4.0 emulator.